# Regular grammar with at most one c

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars

I am attempting to make a regular grammar over alphabet {a, b, c} where there is at most one c. So far, I have the regular expression `((a|b)*|c)(a|b)*` but am unsure where to go from here; my previous attempts have ended up allowing multiple c's.

The solution I has gives (N={s,t}, T={a,b,c}, s, R), s→є, s→as, s→bs, s→ct, t→at, t→bt, t→є, however I do not see how this limits the number of c's generated to at most 1.

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't match $aca$.

Comment: Seems you want something like _prefix_ c[opt] _suffix_ where _prefix_ and _suffix_ are `(a|b)*`. It's clear that neither prefix nor suffix contain a `c` so there can be at most one `c` from the optional `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule s->ct can only be done once, becuase after that there is no more s left, and from t you cannot generate more s. Thus at most one c can be generated, because no other rule generates c.

Also the rest of the grammar looks fine.

Comment: Could we apply s→as or s→bs then s→ct to obtain more s, then use these to obtain more c?

Comment: Sorry, I see my obvious mistake now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should reason: It contains no $c$ or one $c$.

If no $c$, it is $(a|b)^*$.

If exactly one $c$, it has "no c" before the lonely $c$ and "no c" after, i.e., $(a|b)^*c(a|b)^*$.

Join them to get $(a|b)^*|(a|b)^*c(a|b)^*$. Or you could factorize to give $(a|b)^*(\epsilon|c(a|b)^*)$.

Comment: Although the regular expression in the question is wrong, the question itself is asking for a regular grammar, not a regular expression.